# How can I prevent other coders from bypassing my wrapper function?

Tags: c++, class, oop, wrapper

I have a C++ class that handles logs (ClassLog), and I implement an instance of this class in my own class (ClassWork). Since I need timestamps in my ClassWork logs, I added a wrapper function that adds the current time to every new line, before sending the characters to be written to ClassLog.

That means anyone adding new log outputs in ClassWork MUST use my wrapper function, otherwise the log will be messed up (missing timestamps). However, ClassLog has a public member function that allows anyone to bypass my wrapper function, and write directly to the log. Is there something I can do to have an instance of ClassLog in ClassWork, yet prevent ClassWork from accessing ClassLog public member functions unless they are accessed from my wrapper function? This would make it impossible for another coder to accidentally screw up the logs.

Comment: Does the function that allows you to bypass your wrapper really have to be public?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have authority on ClassLog, as it is a class that has been developed a long time ago and is used everywhere in the code my team uses. For this reason anyone can write using the instance of ClassLog declared in my ClassWork. The instance of ClassLog itself is private, but I'm worried about people adding code to ClassWork using ClassLog print directly instead of my wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your wrapper function `const`, and make the variable which holds the string a mutable, so that a const function can still modify it.

```
class ClassLog {

    mutable std::string log;

    public: 
    const std::string writeToLog(std::string logToWrite) const 
    {
        log = logToWrite;
        return log;
    };
}

class classWork {

    ClassLog logs;

    public: 
    const void wrapper();
}
```

Comment: It will allow ClassWork to only access the private and protected members of ClassLog. I will update my answer with more info I think may help.

Comment: A `const void` return type?

Comment: Yea, that's wrong. Feel free to edit my code. I was just trying to prove a point.

Answer (score 0):

Options that I can think of:

1. Don't expose `ClassLog` as a class. Make it an implementation detail of `ClassWork`.
2. Make the relevant member function of `ClassLog` private. Declare `ClassWork` a friend of `ClassLog`.
3. Make the time stamp a required argument in the member function of `ClassLog`.
4. Make the time stamp an optional argument in the member function of `ClassLog`. If it is not provided, compute the time stamp using current time and add that to the log.

Answer (score 0):

Is the logging method of ClassLog virtual? If so, make your own, specialized implementation of ClassLog; let's call it ClassWorkLog. Use this in your ClassWork instead of the ClassLog. For example:

```
class ClassLog {
public:
    virtual void writeToLog(std::string message) { ... }
    ...
};

// Implement wrapper class
class ClassWorkLog : ClassLog {
public:
    virtual void writeToLog(std::string message) override {
        std::string timestamp = getTimeStamp();
        ClassLog::writeToLog(timestamp + message);
    }
};
```

If it isn't extendable, you can use composition instead, where your wrapper class holds a ClassLog:

```
// Implement wrapper class
class ClassWorkLog {
public:
    void writeToLog(std::string message) {
        std::string timestamp = getTimeStamp();
        classLog.writeToLog(timestamp + message);
    }

private:
    ClassLog classLog;
};
```

Now, in ClassWork, use your ClassWorkLog wrapper class instead of the standard ClassLog.

```
class ClassWork {
public:
    void doStuff() {
        ...
        workLog.writeToLog("test");
    }

private:
    ClassWorkLog workLog;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Derive your own logging class from ClassLog and store an instance of that (or inject it via the constructor).  Then override the public logging function with your own.  Ideally the logging method should be virtual in the base though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ClassLog
{
    public:
    void Log(string message)
    {
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
    }
};

class DerivedClassLog : public ClassLog
{

    private:
    const std::string currentDateTime() 
    {
        time_t     now = time(0);
        struct tm  tstruct;
        char       buf[80];
        tstruct = *localtime(&now);
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d.%X", &tstruct);

        return buf;
    }

    public:
    void Log(string message)
    {
        ClassLog::Log(currentDateTime() + " " + message);
    }
};

int main()
{
   DerivedClassLog logger;

   logger.Log("Hello");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't inherit and specialize like the other answers suggest.  Instead, I would use a wrapper class whose `ClassLog` member is private.

```
class TimestampedLog
{
public:
    write(std::string msg) {
        log.write(getCurrentTime());
        log.write(msg);
    }
private:
    ClassLog log;
};

class ClassWork
{
public:
    void doSomething() {
        // ...
        log.write("Did something");
    }
private:
    TimestampedLog log;
};
```